# Keurig and K-Cups in Checked Luggage

Tags: customs-and-immigration, luggage, indonesia, import-taxes, indonesian-citizens

I'm an Indonesian college student studying at U.S. Going back home for summer break this May with a rather absurd luggage:

136 K-Cups and a Keurig Coffee Machine.

Why? Because I love coffee.

I already checked TSA's site and they said both Keurig and K-Cups are fine. Also, it's worth much less than $250 (already printed the invoice) so I shouldn't get into any trouble in Indonesian customs.

However, the amount of K-Cups worries me. I read from various traveling guide websites that 'excessive' amount raises suspicions on both US TSA agents and Indonesian customs officers. I really don't want them to tear up my K-Cups to inspect it for a very obvious reason: opening the cup will ruin the coffee.

This is the first time I'm traveling back home with such weird luggage, so am I going to get into any trouble for it? Any experience with a large amount of luggage?

I will really appreciate your answer!
Thanks

Comment: From a commercial perspective 136 cups is nothing. Typically customs gets concerned if you are importing enough to resell them [so probably upwards of 5000].

Comment: Your request is so specific, the only way to get a real answer is to just go ahead and fly. Given the small cost of the cups it shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: OMG you are really bringing coffee from the US to Indonesia....???

Comment: @Calchas I see. I shouldn't be worried about 136 K-cups, then. Thank you!

Comment: @JonathanReez it is a big deal. Any Keurig products are not available in Indonesia and shipping it over can cost over $175, more expensive than the machine and all the 136 K-Cups combined. If some random TSA agent or Indonesian customs officer decided to rip open all the K-Cups to make sure it's not drugs due to its excessive amount, that would really upset me.

Comment: @Axel I know it's a bit weird. Even some of my K-Cups are Sumatra coffee, which originates from Indonesia. It's like buying back what the US has bought from Indonesia. But the thing is, Keurig and K-Cups are not sold at Indonesia. There are other coffee machines available but they are either manual or outrageously expensive due to import tax. My family in Indonesia loves coffee so I suppose a Keurig is a great product to bring home.

Comment: Instead of re-importing a bunch of coffee to Indonesia, you might want to consider buying a reusable K-cup filter or three.  They're a bit of a hassle to wash, but they'll allow your family to use the thing indefinitely, instead of it becoming useless when the pre-packaged cups run out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps in this time of immigration uncertainties you are overthinking a minor issue. TSA are not dumb people (although some of their decisions may make one inclined to think so) and will know what K-cups are and that their value is minuscule. At worst they will tear one open which I doubt.

If anything it will be the Indonesian customs officers who will be chuckling however even then confirming the commercial value is minor can easily be confirmed.

My assertion is based on the fact that I do quite a lot of traveling and have carried large quantities of similarly cheap consumables and never had a problem here or abroad.